# How can I implement the ability to add a new task to an existing list (project) or to a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want possibility to adding new task to an existing list(project), or to a new one. I have 2 models: Project and Todo.
Project has_many :todos, Todo belongs_to :project
I wrote some code that give me possibility to create task

```
class Api::V1::TodosController < ApiController  
 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
     @todo = Todo.new(todo_params_on_create)

      if @todo.save
       render json: @todo, status: :created 
    else 
      render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end  
  end

    private
   def todo_params_on_create
     params.require(:todo).permit(:text, :checked, :project_id) 
  end
end
```

But i can create task only for existing project, because of the association and i need to pass project_id in todos request
May you please help, how I can implement creating new task with new project?

P.S. I thought that I need to implement some method in the project model and call it before saving the new task. Maybe something like this (but pass the title value in the todos request):

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord 
  has_many :todos   before_save :new_project, unless: :self.nil?  

  def new_project 
    self.update_columns(title: "NewProject")
   end  

end
```

But I think I'm wrong in my thoughts.

Comment: Use `belongs_to :project, optional: true` in Todo model.

Comment: @kishorecheruku thanks for advice! How can I create a task in connection with a new project? So that when creating a new task, a new project is created at the same time with a filled title value and the new task is linked to the new project.

Comment: You want to have nested_attributes for the project model. [Here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes) is a nice atricle with explanation and sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For creating your Todo element without a Project**, use as mentioned in the comment `belongs_to :project, optional: true`

**For creating your Todo element together with a new Project**

Some **quick dirty ways** would be to just create the Project entity before creating the Todo entity in your Todo Controller (if you want it only when created through this controller)

```
class Api::V1::TodosController < ApiController 
  def create
    todo = Todo.new(todo_params_on_create)
    if todo.project_id.nil?
      project = Project.create(title: "NewProject")
      todo.project_id = project.id
    end
    if todo.save    
      render json: todo, status: :create
    else
      render json: todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

or in your Todo model (if you want it whenever a Todo is created)

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord

  before_create :create_project, unless: :project_id

  def create_project
    project = Project.create(title: "NewProject")
    self.project_id = project.id
  end
end
```

The issue with this approaches is the case where the creation of Todo object fails, you will still have a Project object created in your database. A solution to that would be to delete the Project object in case of failure but that is still error prone.

The more **correct solution** is to just use Transactions and Error handling to handle the creation/deletion of the objects but that also come with an added overhead:

```
class Api::V1::TodosController < ApiController 
  def create
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        todo = Todo.new(todo_params_on_create)
        if todo.project_id.nil?
          project = Project.create!(title: "NewProject")
          todo.project_id = project.id
        end
        todo.save!
        render json: todo, status: :create
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      //Handle error message
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! And how can I instead of the hardcode title, pass the value of the title in the request when i create a task?

Comment: `title: params[:title]` if you have the title passed as a parameter